# Алгоритмы сортировки? Что к чему?

Tags: алгоритм

В чем разница между сортировками обменными и между сортировками вставками. Или же в чем разница между сортировками со сравнениями и без сравнений?
Например: почему предпочтительнее быстрая сортировка Хоара, вместо алгоритма сортирвоки Шелла?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ywWBy6J5gz8?list=RDywWBy6J5gz8

Comment: Спасибо большое, правда я уже разобрался как работают алгоритмы сортировки основные, кроме поразрядной. Но мне другое интересно почему же Хоар предпочтительнее Шелла?

Comment: Не совсем понятен первый вопрос. Сортировки in-place, как ни верти, всегда будут обменными. На сортировки out-of-place такого требования не накладывается. О каких сортировках вы говорите?

Comment: Прочитал то что написал и понял, что ошибся я во всем. Пойду разбираться во всем. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Этому вопросу целые книги посвящены. К примеру, третий том «искусство программирования» Кнута. Попробуйте сузить вопрос до одной конкретной проблемы.